# Get next token type in Ace Editor

Tags: ace-editor

With the session you are able to get a token using:

```
token = session.getTokenAt(row, column);
token.type; // text.xml
```

Is there a way to get the next token type?

```
token = session.getTokenAt(row, column);
token.type; // text.xml
token = session.getNextToken(token);
token.type; // meta.tag.punctuation.end-tag-open.xml
```

I have a value that has a data URI string and I would like to skip to the next token.

Example XML:

```
<data>
    abcdef...
    abcdef...
    ...5000 more rows...
</data>
```

Example XML attribute:

```
<data src="abcdef...5000 characters..." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use token iterator

```
var TokenIterator = require("ace/token_iterator").TokenIterator;
var stream = new TokenIterator(session, row, column);
next = stream.stepForward()
```

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.8/lib/ace/mode/folding/latex.js#L87